# I am trying to create a payara cluster and I get an error during creation of a remote node

Tags: linux, system, continuous-deployment, payara

I am trying to create a payara cluster and I get an error during creation of a remote node:

```
./asadmin create-node-ssh --nodehost 10.198.228.240  --sshkeyfile /root/.ssh/id_rsa --force true --install true computer2

Enter admin user name>  admin
Enter admin password for user "admin">
Created installation zip /root/payara5/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/glassfish1664073687432568371.zip
Successfully connected to root@10.198.228.240 using keyfile /root/.ssh/id_rsa
Copying /root/payara5/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/glassfish1664073687432568371.zip (146575218 bytes) to 10.198.228.240:/root/payara5
Installing glassfish1664073687432568371.zip into 10.198.228.240:/root/payara5
jar command failed while installing glassfish on host 10.198.228.240. Command output bash: jar: command not found

Command install-node-ssh failed.

Remote command output: bash: jar: command not found
Command create-node-ssh executed successfully.
```

Is there a solution for this issue?

```
jar command failed while installing glassfish on host 10.198.228.240. Command output bash: jar: command not found
```

Answer (score 1):

the solution is : 
1- add a path of jdj to /root/.bashrc :
    export JAVA_HOME=/opt/java-jdk/jdk1.8.0_201
    export PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
2- source .bashrc
3- check witch jar executable shell was trynig to execute :
  $ which jar
   /opt/java-jdk/jdk1.8.0_201/bin/jar
4- Now create a symbolic link to the jar executable file frome /usr/bin directory
    # cd /usr/bin/
    #  ln -s /opt/java-jdk/jdk1.8.0_201/bin/jar
    #  which jar
      /usr/bin/jar

after that create node-ssh frome computer1 :

root@computer1:~/payara5/bin# ./asadmin create-node-ssh --nodehost computer2  --sshkeyfile /root/.ssh/id_rsa --force true --install true computer2-node
    Enter admin user name>  admin
    Enter admin password for user "admin">
    Successfully installed Payara on computer2.
    Command create-node-ssh executed successfully.

Comment: The points 3- and 4- were exactly what I needed to solve the issue when trying to configure a simple Payara cluster on Virtual Box Ubuntu virtual machines..

Comment: In my case, I ran ''cd /usr/bin", and then "ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_271/bin/jar", because my Oracle JDK was installed in that directory. I also had to run "sudo rm ./jar" before, to solve the error that the file was already existing for me.